# Nodejs treating string as a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Alright, I have a function

```js
function foo(input) {
    input = input.split("\n");
    console.log(input);
}
```

and the input is `'alert("gsasdgasdg")'` so `foo('alert("gsasdgasdg")')`
the output I get when I run it in nodejs is the expected output: `[ 'alert("gsasdgasdg")' ]`
`
Now I will add a simple loop,

```js
function foo(input) {
    var output = "";
    input = input.split("\n");
    console.log(input);
    for (var i in input) {
        console.log(input[i]);
    }
}
```

Now I get the first `console.log` output as `[ 'alert("gsasdgasdg")' ]`
 (expected) but there should be only one `console.log` when it loops through the array, what I get is `alert("gsasdgasdg")`
 (expected) and then `[Function]` as far as I know nodejs should have not of converted this string into a function, any insight that explains why this happens?

Comment: The reason you get Array brackets for the first one and not the second, is because in the first one `input` is an array when `input[i]` is the value for the index `i` and therefor not an array.

Comment: @GillesC That was not the question, what I'm trying to ask is why input[1] is a function.

Comment: Did you check it was actually a function? To see if it's the logging that is wrong or if it is node actually changing a string to a function.

Comment: `       try  {
            input[i]()
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }` did a quick test and this doesn't throw anything for input[1]

Comment: There's something in your code that attaches itself to `Array.prototype`

Comment: There are modifications to the string prototype (rot13) but thats it

Comment: @DrGoat: try `console.log(i, input[i])`...

Comment: turns out it was going through the prototype as well